# buscar solo una parte de texto en letras que cabían

Tags: linux

tengo el siguiente problema... quiero buscar las siguientes palabras: (hola como (estas))

y mi archivo3.txt contiene: (hola como (estas)) qué has (hecho)

y el detalle es que: hola como (estas) cambia constante a cualquier otra frase. por ejemplo:

Ejemplo1 (hola como (estas)) qué has (hecho)

Ejemplo2 (que tal(robert)) qué has (hecho)

Ejemplo3 (dime) qué has (hecho)

Ejemplo infinito!!!!!!!

entonces quiero buscar la primera que encontré, nada más una sola y sin mostrar el texto: qué has (hecho)

probe esto:

awk '{imprimir $3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9}' ip.txt | cola -n 1 | cortar -d' ' -f6

pero me busca lo que no quiero que es: qué tiene (hecho)

y también probé esto: grep "(. . .*" ip.txt | head -1 | cut -d '(' -f 2-3 pero este me suprime (estas), (robert) y (dime) cuando encuentra cualquier ejemplo entre las infinitas palabras

Comment: ¿qué quiere decir que "cambia constante a cualquier otra frase"? ¿puedes darnos un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y la salida que esperas?

Comment: el detalle es que: hola como (estas) cambia constante a cualquier otra frase. por ejemplo:

Ejemplo1 (hola como (estas)) qué has (hecho)

Ejemplo2 (que tal(robert)) qué has (hecho)

Ejemplo3 (dime) qué has (hecho)

Ejemplo infinito!!!!!!!

Comment: Prueba con  *grep -m1 -o -E '^[(]([^)]+?)[)][)]?\s' archivo3.txt* que te muestra la primera linea que cumpla. Si quieres que muestre todas quita el parametro *m1*

Comment: grep -oE '\(.*' ip3.txt | head -1 | cut -d ')' -f1 | sed 's/(//g' | tr -d '\r' me funciona mejor así pero me funciona aveces y aveces muestra alguna parte de lo que no quiero

Comment: grep -m1 -oE '[(].*[)]' ip3.txt | head -n 1 | cut -d')' -f 1 | sed 's/(//g' de esta forma también funcióna pero éste no lo e probado con el módulo qué me lo hace cambiar, más luego les digo